# function does not take 1 arguments c++

Tags: c++, function, boolean, return

I'm having issue with my code, in that I can't figure out why I'm receiving an error. Here is the code:

```
using namespace std;

void presentValue();
bool stringChar();
bool stringVal();
double futureValConv();

int main()
{
  cout << "Welcome to the Present Value Interest Calculator!\n\"First, let me collect some data." << endl << endl;
  presentValue();
  return 0;
}

void presentValue()
{
  //declare variables
  //Response value intialized as x for debugging
  char response = 'x';

  while (response != 'n' || response != 'N')
  {
    //declare variables
    double intRate = 0;
    string futureValString;
    double futureVal;
    double years = 0;

    //Simple present value equation
    double presentVal = futureVal / pow((intRate + 1), years);

    cout << "What's your Interest Rate?  ";
    cin >> intRate;
    cout << "OK, and what's your desired Future Value? [H}elp  ";
    cin >> futureVal;
    //Run descending help program that won't allow escape without a double value
    **futureVal = futureValConv(futureValString);**
    cout << endl << endl << "And finally, how many years would you like to save your money for?  ";
    cin >> years;
    cout << endl << "You've made it this far!!!";
    cout << endl << endl << presentVal;

  }
}
inline double futureValConv(string somestring)
{
  //delcare variables
  double newString = 0;

  **if (stringChar(somestring))**
  {
    cout << endl << "Future Value is the amount you would like to have in your account in the future.\n\n";
    cout << "How much might that be?  ";
    cin >> somestring;
    futureValConv(somestring);

  }
  **else if(stringVal(somestring))**
  {
    //Convert the Future Value String to a double for future use
    newString = atoi(somestring.c_str());
  }  
  else
  {
    cout << "Please enter a proper value.  ";
    futureValConv(somestring);
  }

  return newString;
}

bool stringChar(string response)
{
  //declare variables
  char answer = response[0];
  bool status = false;

  if (answer == 'H' || answer == 'h')
  {
    status = true;
    return status;
  }
}

bool stringVal(string response)
{
  //declare varialbes
  int answer = atoi(response.c_str());
  bool status = false;
  int powZero = (answer, 0);

  if (powZero == 1)
  {
    status = true;
    return status;
  }

}
```

I posted most of my code because I can't grasp what is going on here.  It is telling me that stringChar and stringVal do not take 1 arguments, as well as futureValConv. I am attempting to run a function checking the value of a string, and determining what the value is before making a decision. In two of the three instances, the function calls itself to run again until the user has entered an acceptable double (Which I check by running to the power of 0 for a an answer of 1.) I have bolded the three lines generating an error. Interestingly, even by commenting out the function futureValConv and never calling into the other functions, I still get two of the three errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared this at the top:

```
bool stringChar();
bool stringVal();
```

So the compiler expects stringChar and stringVal functions to have no arguments.
Change the declaration to:

```
bool stringChar(string response);
bool stringVal(string response);
```

Comment: Special note: this isn't C, where empty parentheses means an unknown number of parameters.

Comment: Apparently I should have learned about function prototypes a bit more before implementing them.  Thanks