# Too few arguments in a function call

Tags: c++

I'm running into an issue where I want to pass 1 argument to a function that takes 1 argument, but this results in a build error.

here is the code I'm using in `main.cpp`:

```
std::string crypt(char* result) {
    sha256_crypt(result);
    std::string str(result);
    return result;
}
```

the error happens when calling the `sha256_crypt(result);` which is in another file (`sha256.c`):

```
void sha256_crypt(char* output) {
    // Do some fun stuff
}
```

In the error list it shows up as:
`'sha256_crypt': function does not take 1 arguments`

I was wondering what I'm doing wrong as I think I am giving enough arguments to the function?

Comment: If the function definition and the call are in different .c files, then most likely there is a header file (`sha256.h`) with the wrong function declaration.

Comment: Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Including possible header files and the declaration of the functions.

Comment: Did you check the other questions on SO that treat exactly the same error message? (Just google "function does not take 1 arguments").

Comment: @rodrigoyou where actually right... thanks! (mind posting it as an answer so I can vote it as the solution?)

Comment: @FinlayRoelofs better not, because that makes this question an exact duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function does not take 1 arguments c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21642513/function-does-not-take-1-arguments-c)

Comment: I thought I had all the stuff right because I was looking at `sha256.c`. in the dupe you say, nobody talked about the `sha256.h` file... so not exactly a dupe...

Comment: The **reason** is the same: declaration is different from usage, No need to create yet another question about the same problem because in the 10 other questions the header file isn't called sha256.h :)

Comment: Try putting a forward declaration `void sha256_crypt(char*);` before the `crypt` function